# Intellij 15 showing errors in html with react components

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

I have the following code in my html:

```
<body>
<div id="greeting-div"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    var Greeting = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
            <p>Hello, Universe</p>
            )
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Greeting/>,
        document.getElementById('greeting-div')
    );
</script>
</body>
```

Intellij is showing errors like "expression expected" near the left paren

```
return (
```

near the p tag

```
</p>
```

among other places. How to get rid of these errors?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues may help you...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, check.

```js
var Greeting = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
            <p>Hello, Universe</p>
            )
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Greeting/>,
        document.getElementById('greeting-div')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="greeting-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it works. I just don't want to see the errors in intellij editor